# How to concisely get the units of a Sympy expression

Tags: python, sympy

I'm working with Sympy expressions that have units. Here's a trivial example:

```
from sympy.physics.units import newton, meter
atmosphere = 101325. * newton / (meter **2)
```

In the above example, is there a concise way to get the units, i.e. `newton / (meter **2)` from the variable `atmosphere`?

Comment: The following code works, at least in the above example. Is it the best way to do this?
`get_units = lambda expr: expr.subs({x: 1 for x in expr.args if x.is_number})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is good, but I would replace the check for `is_number` with `has(Quantity)`

```
from sympy.physics.units import Quantity,
def unit(expr):
    return expr.subs({x: 1 for x in expr.args if not x.has(Quantity)})
```

Then it works also with symbolic amounts, like

```
g = symbols('g')
acc = g*meter/second**2
unit(acc)  # meter/second**2
```

Comment: This solution does not work in some cases: `unit(1*meter)` gives `TypeError: name should be a string, not <class 'sympy.core.numbers.One'>`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking the right answer for my application is actually `expr.as_coeff_Mul()`, which returns the tuple `(c, x)` where c is a number and x is a product of symbols. If your expression is only numbers and units, this will give you `(magnitude, units)` directly.