# sympy: converting physics constants to numerical representation without knowing the final units

Tags: constants, sympy, physics, algebra

In SymPy it looks like it is very hard to evaluate a physics expression to get a final result:

```py
    from IPython.display import display, Latex
    from sympy import *
    import sympy.physics.units as U
    x = symbols('x')
    c = U.speed_of_light
    G = U.gravitational_constant
    hb = U.hbar
    display(sqrt(hb*G/(c**3)))
```

will result in:

[image: equation]

while even the `sqrt(hb*G/(c**3)).evalf()` expression (or simplify, or anything) will just fiddle with exponents, but never combine the constants into some final result.

How will I get what is the approximate **value** of the expression?

(To be honest, there is already a matching question, but the accepted answer is practically useless, because it requires manual steps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51138039/8637159:

1. Print the dimensions of the expression
2. Manually `convert_to` the expression to the units guessed from the dimensions.

This is not acceptable.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a solution, which I absolutely do not like:

```py
    from IPython.display import display, Latex
    from sympy import *
    import sympy.physics.units as U
    c = U.speed_of_light
    G = U.gravitational_constant
    hb = U.hbar
```

and the magic:

```py
    U.convert_to(sqrt(hb*G/(c**3)), U.SI._base_units).evalf()
```

This will display:

```py
    1.61625502442371e-35*meter
```

which is the correct value.

I know it would be enough in this case to include `U.meter` in the list in the second parameter in `U.convert_to()`, but in a generic case, where the expression has **unknown** units (as finding out the final units is part of the problem) it is better to include all basic units, and apparently it does not cause any issues.

I still hate this solution. There should be an obvious way to achieve the same effect.

Comment: The expression does not intrinsically have units. It represents a physical quantity with the *dimension* of length but the units are a choice of representation. If you want to use metres for length rather than inches or nanometres then you need to specify that. Remember that part of the point of the units module is to be able to convert between different kinds of units. Potentially a convenient helper for mks would be useful though.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But in a certain unit system it definitely does have units. The speed of light is equivalent to 299 792 458 m / s in SI units. When you present a value to someone you need to be able to present it in some units. And it is weird if you cannot do this automatically. "Print value in SI" or "print value in CGS" should be an actual operation.

Comment: A better place to discuss this would be in a GitHub issue (linking back to here). In current (1.8) SymPy there is the concept of a "unit system" and both SI and CGS are implemented so you can do `U.convert_to(sqrt(hb*G/(c**3)), SI._base_units)` but there could be a public method with a better name and documentation.

Comment: Yes, exactly. This is what I think. Thanks for the shortcut. (Why the hell is `SI._base_units` private anyway? This does not make any sense.)

Comment: A common reason for things to be private is just that public API needs to be carefully considered and documented and is hard to change in future. It's probably just a case of needing someone to put the work in to design and document the API. The relevant people aren't reading this though which why a GitHub issue is a better place for this discussion.

Comment: Thanks, I will post an issue there.